# create observable for returning csv values

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So, what I am trying to do is read a csv file and have the content
of the file returned as a string.

Now, I need the function to return the filecontent as a string and for this I could use an Observable. My first approach looked like this with observable and filereader:

```
 readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          console.log(fileReader.result);
        }
        fileReader.readAsText(file);  
      }  Observable.create()
return defer(() => {
  loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    return of(resources);
  });
})
```

The filereader here works fine, the observable doesn't.
What would be the correct approach to use an observable or another technology to return the content of my file as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable.create is depreciated. Try the following

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
    return new Observable(obs=>{
        const file = (fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          obs.next(fileReader.result);
          obs.complete();
        }
        fileReader.readAsText(file);  
        return ()=>{ fileReader.onload=null; }
    })
}
```

usuage:

```
this.readDocument(fileEvent).subscribe(documentvalue=>{
 self.chartOptions.data.csv = documentvalue;})
```

Comment: so, this gives me the observable back as an object. How could I for example console.log the value of the observable something like: console.log(readDocument(data))

Comment: readDocument(data).subscribe(res=>console.log(res)), updated the answer to handle unsubscription and clean up the callback

Comment: this works fine with console.log but when i try to use it as a string i get the error: error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'string'. how could I use it as a string?

Comment: I initialize the string like this:     var documentvalue = this.readDocument(data).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));

Comment: and i try to use it with highcharts: self.chartOptions.data.csv = documentvalue;

Comment: this.readDocument(data).subscribe(res=>console.log(res)) is an async operatio and it returns an subscription, you'll have to assign it inside subscribe, something similar to promise.then()

Comment: could you add this to your solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199242/discussion-between-j-doe-and-fan-cheung).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using observable properly. if you want to create new Observable you have to do it like this:

```
readDocument(fileChangeEvent: Event) {
  Observable.create(observer => {
    // do all your stuf here:
    // then emit the value:
    observer.next(values);

    // after everything is done let the observable to complete:
    observer.complete();
  }
}
```

**source:** https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html

Hope it was helpful.